# Setting port number of socketio on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

I was trying to make a chat with javascript and npm.
Since it was completed to some extent, it was deployed to heroku, and it was displayed as `net :: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in chrome's developer tool.
I think that socketio, express, heroku are the cause of the error.
The URL of the site is here:
https://reax-chat.herokuapp.com/public/

That code is in here.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const portNumber = process.env.PORT || 3005

server.listen(portNumber, () => {
  console.log('起動しました', 'http://localhost:' + portNumber)
})

app.use('/public', express.static('./public'))
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.redirect(302, '/public')
})

const socketio = require('socket.io')
const io = socketio.listen(server)

io.on('connection',(socket) => {
  console.log('Acces to User:', socket.client.id)
  socket.on('chatMessage',(msg) => {
    console.log('message',msg)
    io.emit('chatMessage',msg)
  })
})
```

How can I resolve this error?
Thank you.

Comment: I changed the deploy destination from heroku to firebase. Thank you for anser

Answer (score 0):

You are sending request to localhost, but should be sending to your web url. That's what your chrome dev tools network tab should have told you.